# Error Sizing Ground Overlay in Android Maps V2 API

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I’m positioning a ground overlay on a map.
Using the following code I can position the bitmap:

```
LatLng logAnchor = new LatLng(50.7738,7.28046);

GroundOverlayOptions mGroundOverlayOptions =new GroundOverlayOptions()

.image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.hennef))

.anchor(0, 0)

.bearing(15)

.position(logAnchor, 59);

testGroundOverlay = mMap.addGroundOverlay(mGroundOverlayOptions);
```

When I try to make the bitmap bigger and bigger then when I change from 58 to 59 meters the overlay jumps and get more bigger then expected on the map.
Does anyone know if this is a bug or do I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In GMAP API v2 u can see

> **Position
>           ... You can optionally provide the height of the overlay (in meters). If you do not provide the height of the overlay, it will be automatically calculated to preserve the proportions of the image**.
>
> Just try use position(logAnchor, float Width, float Height)

Comment: i tried to use with and without the height. The function works fins but in both cases when I increase the size of the display of my bitmap on the ground suddenly the dispayed size does not correctly corelate to the parameters I user for the width in the function call. In my case inceasing from 58m to 59m in width doubles the size for the Groundoverlay on the map. I think the function just does not work correctly.